# Linq query DateTime.Date.DayOfWeek

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

Trying to get only Thursdays of 1 year back

```
using (var context = new Context1())
{
      // Get 1 year back only Thursday
      var oneYearEarlier = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);

      var query = (from c in context.Daily25Data
                   where c.Date > oneYearEarlier && c.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday
                   select c).ToList();

      Console.WriteLine(query);
}
```

and getting

> Additional information: The specified type member 'DayOfWeek' is not
>   supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and
>   entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: Seems linq to entity can't translate `DateTime.DayOfWeek` into SQL, which is strange as there are sql methods for that.

Answer (score 8):

[This](http://c-sharp-snippets.blogspot.com/2011/12/getting-dayofweek-in-linq-to-entities.html)  is a clever solution using EntityFunctions.DiffDays

from his post:

```
DateTime firstSunday = new DateTime(1753, 1, 7); 
var bookings = from b in this.db.Bookings 
               where EntityFunctions.DiffDays(firstSunday, b.StartDateTime) % 7 == 1 
               select b;
```

Comment: Nice answer +1 You could eventually replace `EntityFunctions` which now are marked as obsolete with `DbFunctions`.

Comment: DbFunctions throws "Nullable object must have values" exception

Answer (score 0):

LINQ will not recognize the second part of your query into SQL. You need to break your query up in order to perform the filter.

```
using (var context = new algoventurelab_db1Context())
{
      // Go one year back from current date
      var startDate = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-1);
      // This will get all dates in context greater than start date.
      var query1 = (from c in context.Daily25Data
                   where c.Date >= startDate
                   select c).AsEnumerable();
      //this will filter only thurdays
      var query = from c in query1
                  where c.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday
                  select c).ToList();

      Console.WriteLine(query);
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `ToList` you could instead use `AsEnumerable`.  That way you don't need to create the intermediate list.

Comment: Current date `2016 mar 30 is Wednesday`, so `.AddYears(-1)` will give you `2015 mar 30 is Wednesday` that is monday. not `Wednesday` as you expected

Comment: I thought the first ToList was to materialize the query. It would work with `AsEnumerable`? If so I've just learned something new.

Comment: @Nkosi:  no i was misunderstanded, its fine

Comment: `AsEnumerable` just switches it over from a `IQueryable` to an `IEnumerable` so that any Linq operations done after it will be done in Linq-to-Objects and thus not converted to SQL.